# Positive real root separation

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let $\beta\in(1,2)$ and $\gamma\in(1,2)$ be Galois conjugates of height 1. That is, there exists a polynomial $p$ with coefficients $-1,0,1$ such that $p(\beta)=p(\gamma)=0$  (not necessarily minimal).

Numerically, there appears to be an absolute constant $C>0$ such that $|\gamma-\beta|\ge C$. Is this true/known? If it is, what is the best known value for $C$?

I've looked into some literature on root separation but couldn't find this claim.

Comment: [Chapter 9](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-21652-2_9) deals with a similar problem, but the bound depends on $\beta$ (naturally, there are many results like that). The hight could be a red herring, as any polynomial with Mahler measure less than 2, always divides a polynomial of height 1. However, asking for an absolute bound might complicate the matter, and could potentially relate to Lehmer's conjecture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The polynomial

$$1 + x^n + x^{2n} - x^{3n} - x^{5n} - x^{6n} + x^{7n}$$

is irreducible and has two Galois conjugate roots $\beta_n$ and $\gamma_n$ in $(1,2)$ with

$$| \beta_n - \gamma_n| \sim  \frac{\log(\beta_1/\gamma_1)}{n} \rightarrow 0.$$

Comment: Simple and beautiful! Maybe the irreducibilty (at least for infinitely many $n$, like the primes) deserves an explanation.

Comment: Since the Galois group of the polynomial $p(x)$ for $n = 1$ is $S_7$, the irreducibility of $p(x^n)$ is immediate as long as a (any) root of $p(x)$ is not a perfect $n$th power for some $n > 1$. But any root is a fundamental unit in the corresponding degree $7$ field.

Comment: Thanks! I posted a follow-up question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314870/positive-real-root-separation-v2